# How to analyze the performance report if the application doesn't have access to any Monitoring tool

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

Had asked in an recent interview that if an Application doesn't have access to any monitoring and profiling tool then how do you analyze the report.

How can we identify any issues like bottlenecks, slow calls , CPU and Memory utilizations etc..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any access to application-side metrics you can only provide analysis using the metrics from the performance testing tool.

The maximum you can do is to run a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) to wit start with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load. Normally application's under test throughput (number of requests per second) should increase proportionally to the increasing load. However I assume that at certain point you will see that despite the load increase the throughput doesn't or even goes down. The moment just before that is known as [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) - the point of maximum system's performance. This is how many users / requests per second the application under test can serve.

You won't be able to state where the bottleneck is without access to application logs, profiler tool telemetry, [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) ,etc. You can guess the reason of the bottleneck or error by looking at response codes/messages or if there are connection timeouts assume that the appplication is overloaded

If you have access to the application under test infrastructure you can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) or [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon) for getting the data from the application under test side.